# Tensorflow android demo use custom model with multi-input

Tags: android, tensorflow

I have a pre-trained model , which use `batch_norm` at the training phase, when I try to use this model to my android , it return output as fixed value.

So I try to make two input for my model: "`images`" and "`phase_train`" : the `images` is the vector of the picture, and `phase_train` is set to `False` to unable `batch_norm`, so how can I set multi input for my model on android?

```
  public static Classifier create(
      AssetManager assetManager,
      String modelFilename,
      String labelFilename,
      int numClasses,
      int inputSize,
      int inputSize1,
      String inputName,
      String outputName)
      throws IOException {
    TensorFlowImageClassifier c = new TensorFlowImageClassifier();
    c.inputName = inputName;        # the input is seted here
    c.outputName = outputName;
```

Comment: the code to  set input is  [click_here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/android/src/org/tensorflow/demo/TensorFlowImageClassifier.java#L84)

Comment: Are you just changing an inception model or is this a brand new model you've made?

Comment: It's a new model that I made for face recognization , which is based on inception network,

Comment: Oh right ok. Is it made via tensorflow for poets but with an extra input?

Comment: Yes,  I need an extra input as a flag to ignore "batch_norm" , for I have only one photo as input per time.

Comment: So do you always want to ignore batch norm as you're only doing inference?

Comment: Yes ,  I'd only want to run without batch_norm on my mobile . Once I set a input value as a flag to ignore the batch_norm , but it seems that tensorflow on android doesn't support multi input

Comment: It certainly does. It's just that the demo code you are using is not giving you that option. You could look at using the android/java functions to pass to the session like you would a feed_dict. OR why dont you just rebuild your model with the flag set to off. If you're never going to need to use it on mobile then just set it to off? I don't have enough experience in this area to help you much further i'm afriad.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I wil try to rebuild my model to set the batch norm ignored.